# SQL Get all records older than 30 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

Now I've found a lot of similar SO questions including an old one of mine, but what I'm trying to do is get any record older than 30 days but my table field is unix_timestamp. All other examples seem to use DateTime fields or something. Tried some and couldn't get them to work.

This definitely doesn't work below. Also I don't want a date between a between date, I want all records after 30 days from a unix timestamp stored in the database. 
I'm trying to prune inactive users.

simple examples.. doesn't work.

```
SELECT * from profiles WHERE last_login < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

And tried this

```
SELECT * from profiles WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Not too strong at complex date queries. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Does Postgresql even have a UNIX_TIMESTAMP function?

Comment: Not sure.. that might be why its not working.. lol

Comment: **I suggest a reopen**, this is a pure postgresql question. Making it the dupe of a mixed mysql/postgresql question looks ugly.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * from profiles WHERE to_timestamp(last_login) < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'
```

Quote from the manual:

> A single-argument to_timestamp function is also available; it accepts a double precision argument and converts from Unix epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp with time zone. (Integer Unix epochs are implicitly cast to double precision.)

Comment: I actually got it to work using `< EXTRACT(epoch from NOW() - INTERVAL '30 DAY')` Not realizing at first postgresql didn't have unix timestamp. Since yours works as well, I'll accept it. Thx

Comment: It would be good to provide a direct link to your source, the specific part of the manual.

Comment: The `to_timestamp()` function is available from PostgreSQL 9.6+.

Answer (score 64):

Unless I've missed something, this should be pretty easy:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE last_login < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days';
```

Comment: @Pjack: ah, so I did have missed something. What is the type of the `last_login` column? I've assumed it was `TIMESTAMP` which it obviously isn't.

Comment: The column is a bigint

Comment: Works perfectly in Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
SELECT * from profiles WHERE last_login < VALUEOFUNIXTIME30DAYSAGO
```

or

```
SELECT * from profiles WHERE last_login < (extract(epoch from now())-2592000)
```

Have a look at this post:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/how-do-i-get-the-current-unix-timestamp-from-postgresql

and this

http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using Postgres:

```
SELECT *
FROM profiles
WHERE
    to_timestamp(last_login) < NOW() - '30 days'::INTERVAL
```