# send us an email after 10 days to the user

Tags: php, mysqli

That is how I have set my cron job to run every minute, it such that this sciprt must say to himself that I log into the site 14 days ago at 14:32 Danish time. So it must send an email to users after 10 days at 14:32 Danish time.

I've tried to look at it here:

[SQL Get all records older than 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997990/sql-get-all-records-older-than-30-days)

```
    $sql = "SELECT bruger.id, bruger.brugernavn, bruger.fornavn, bruger.efternavn FROM bruger INNER JOIN ipbruger ON bruger.id=ipbruger.brugerid WHERE ipbruger.dato_tid < NOW() - INTERVAL '10 days'";
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql))
{ 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $brugernavn, $fornavn, $efternavn);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $navn = $fornavn . " " . $efternavn; 
            $til = $brugernavn; 

            $email_admin = "hello@hello.dk";

            $fra = "Savner dig på hello.dk " . "<" . $email_admin . ">";  
            $emne = "Længe siden vi har set dig på hello.dk"; 

            $besked = file_get_contents('mail_missbruger.php');

            $besked = str_replace("%%navn", $navn, $besked); 
            $besked = str_replace("%%brugernavn", $til, $besked); 

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \n";
            $headers .= "From: " . $fra . "\n";

            mail($til, $emne, $besked, $headers); 
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

What I should have looked at is this area to find out when the user last was online on the page.

```
ipbruger.dato_tid < NOW() - INTERVAL '10 days'
```

Comment: `ipbruger.dato_tid < NOW() - INTERVAL '10 days'` should be `ipbruger.dato_tid < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 day`. DAY is singular and no quotes around the interval period.

Comment: John, that should be an answer. The question is pretty confusing, but I think you hit exactly what OP is asking for.

Comment: does it have to be 10 days to the minute? i would throttle that back a bit for the sake of resources

Comment: I do hope you up the time stamp then, or do you plan to spam users < 10 days _every minute_ from that point on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to substract an interval, or `DATE_ADD` to add an interval.

```
$sql = "SELECT bruger.id, bruger.brugernavn, bruger.fornavn, bruger.efternavn FROM bruger INNER JOIN ipbruger ON bruger.id=ipbruger.brugerid WHERE ipbruger.dato_tid < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT bruger.id, bruger.brugernavn, bruger.fornavn, bruger.efternavn FROM bruger INNER JOIN ipbruger ON bruger.id=ipbruger.brugerid WHERE ipbruger.dato_tid > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)";
```