# Delete records in PostgreSQL, older than X days, where X is a parameter

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete records older than a given (as a parameter to the function)  number of days.

There are similar questions (e.g. [SQL Get all records older than 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997990/sql-get-all-records-older-than-30-days)) which recommend to use interval '30 day' but how to make the 30 a parameter?

I have a column with a timestamp and the delete would be done in a function that's in SQL rather than plpgsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an SQL function could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION delold(integer) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE sql STRICT AS
'DELETE FROM mytable
 WHERE tscol < current_timestamp
               - ($1::text || '' days'')::interval';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code in the Definition tab in pgadmin, in the code text area is: with deleted as 
(delete from mytable 
where eventdate < now() - ($1::text || ' days')::interval
returning *)
select count( * ) from deleted, so that the function returns the number of rows deleted.

Comment: `RETURNING 1` would be cheaper.