# Select records using records' column value as interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to get all the jobs that are "past due" based on the columns `last_run`, which is a timestamp and `interval_in_hours` which is an integer. I saw from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997990/sql-get-all-records-older-than-30-days) how to select records older than a static interval. How can I use the value of one of the columns in the interval? Something like

```sql
-- ... | interval_in_hours | last_run --
SELECT * from jobs WHERE last_run < NOW() - INTERVAL '<interval_in_hours> hours'
```

I could add a column that tracks something like `next_run_time` and gets updated each time the job gets executed, though it is derived data. Is the performance significantly better for the latter approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `make_interval`:

```
SELECT * 
from jobs 
WHERE last_run < NOW() - make_interval(hours => interval_in_hours);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm seeing `function make_interval(hours => bigint) does not exist`, but I'm guessing that might be an issue with my Postgres?

Comment: When I changed the type of  the `interval_in_hours` column to `int4` from `int8`, it worked

Comment: `make_interval(hours => interval_in_hours::INT);` also works if  `interval_in_hours` is a  `BIGINT` (`int8`)